# Converting Generic to Integer Using InstanceOf

Tags: generics, java-8, casting

I am currently trying to implement a Hashmap on Java on my own as practice for data structures. Currently, I am facing a problem that I cannot seem to overcome and I cannot figure out a workaround for this. For this implementation, I class each key-value pair as a class Entry, with the value being a generic type T and the key guaranteed to be a String. With the code looking something like

```
class Entry<T> {
    private String key;
    private T value;
    private boolean removed;
    //a bunch of public getter setter methods for the 3 fields
```

And now, I want to implement an insert method taking in arguments (String key, T value). One caveat, however, is that if the key already exists in the hashmap and the corresponding value is already an integer, then we simply add the existing value to the inserting value. For this implementation, I did something like:

```
//a function that finds the position of the key that is part of a public class called HashTable
public void put(String key, T value){
    int i = searchKey(key);
    if(i != -1 && value instanceof Integer && hTable[i].getValue() instanceof Integer){
        //returns -1 if the key is not in the hashmap

        Integer temp = (Integer)hTable[i].getValue();

        //hTable is an array that represents the hashmap
        hTable[i].setValue((T) (temp + (Integer) value));
    }
    //some more else if and else statement that is not relevant to this problem
}
```

With this, Java displays the error `Cannot cast from int to T`, which I am very confused as I have already specified that it must be an instanceof Integer, so why can it not do such a thing? Since this is obviously illegal, what is a work around (and why doesn't Java allow such a thing)?

I have tried different type casts, by typecasting from T to integer then back again, or vice versa. I am expecting that this should be legal as I have a previous if-statement to check if the generic is indeed an instance of Integer. I also cannot just simply restrict type T during my class declaration to extending Number or Integer since it can technically take on other data types.

Comment: Does the `setValue` method happen to accept a `T`? If yes, then that's likely where the compilation error is coming from.

Comment: Yeah.... I set it as public void setValue(T value){this.value = value;}

Comment: Since this is the case, how should I edit that method so that it accepts integers

Comment: You don't. If you must do this, then _explicitly_ cast back to a `T`. You'll get a compiler warning, but you can suppress it. I should point out that it's very strange your _generic_ class wants to handle integers specially. And if you were using, or implementing, the `Map` interface, then what you're doing seems more appropriate for the `merge` method.

Comment: This is a weird behavior that will surprise anyone. So, for all other value types, `put` will do what the `Map` contract demands, i.e. just put that value, but if the value happens to be an `Integer`, the behavior changes to adding values? What if `T` is `Number`? Then, I can still put `Integer` values, but I can also put `Double` values, so the values will be added, if the old and new value happens to be `Integer`, but not if either is `Double`? You should decide. Either, you code is *generic* or it has *specific* behavior for specific types.